# ORCA - 7 zip - Language settings and Associations

Tags: configuration, windows-installer, lang, orca

I'm using ORCA to configure the 7-zip MSI file . 
I want the install to be quite and i found the cmdline to allow that, but is there anyway that i can control from within the msi ,which files would be associated to 7-zip and to change the FM interface to English ?

Thanks for your help. 
Noam.

Comment: install 7-zip quite is by using the following cmd line :  'msiexec.msi /i "<path>\<installfile>.msi /q'          the '/q'  allows quite install

Answer (score 0):

I could find a way to control the 7-zip file type associations , 
but in order to change the language to English by default , I've add a cmd line 
to rename the he.txt file to a diffrent name.

```
ren "c:\program files\7-zip\lang\he.txt" he1.txt
```

the result is that the 7-zip file manager will open in English.